# Some prepositions - confusion

Tags: prepositions

Please can you tell me which of the two prepositions in the examples below are correct? Is it possible to use both of them? Thanks! :)

> Translate text **into** German   /   Translate text **to** German
>
> It started to snow **at** Christmas   /   It started to snow **during**
>   Christmas
>
> To ring Kitty **up**    /  To ring Kitty
>
> It starts **about** eight   /    It starts **around** eight
>
> To travel **around** Europe  /  To travel **through** Europe
>
> He looked **about** himself   /   He looked **around** himself
>
> To give a speech **about**    /    To give a speech **on**

Comment: Each of those pairs shows alternate ways of saying the same thing. Some versions may sound more familiar to an individual's ear, but none can be definitively rejected as wrong.

Comment: Hmmm.. So none of these examples is downright incorrect? Can you pick the ones that are more common?

Comment: There are nuanced differences in most of them. Examples: Travel around vs. through Europe: *around* suggests peripatetic meandering, *through* suggests a more direct purposeful course—but not always. Similarly, Christmas can mean a day or a season: It started to snow *on* Christmas implies the day, while *at* Christmas implies a season (as does *during*). But the latter two could be used for the day itself as well.

Comment: 'On Christmas' is something Americans say, meaning 25th December. We would say 'On Christmas Day'. Americans also tend to speak of  'going through' places, rather than visiting (probably not surprising considering the speed at which they sometimes do it).

Comment: @WS2: You don't know what you're talking about with respect to American English, so kindly soft-pedal the snarky generalizations. In fact, most Americans would use *on* in reference to Christmas *Day*, but might drop the "Day" by way of ellipsis; I've heard Brits do the same, by the way.

Comment: @Robusto Well I've lived in Britain for 63 of my 69 years and I have never heard anyone say 'on Christmas', dropping the 'day' 'by way of ellipsis'. (Would these people say 'on Boxing' for the 26th?) I am not complaining that Americans use it, just noting it as an interesting difference.

Comment: @WS2: It was your gratuitous put-down of the travel habits of Americans that took your comment from "noting an interesting difference" to something a little more provocative.

Comment: Meanwhile I'm putting this on hold, as this is a whole number of entirely unrelated questions in one, many of them duplicates of older questions. This particular mix is rather random and thus too localized, and short of simply saying "all variants are possible", as Robusto did, it is rather hard to answer the question correctly, as adressing only one of the sub-questions incorrectly invalidates the answer as a whole. Case in point: the answer you accepted, which is perfectly fine in some respects, but awfully wrong in others. Also, what variety of English are we talking about anyway?

Comment: As I have noted before an American trying to pass himself off as British or vice-versa, might well learn all the alternative spelling and vocabulary perfectly, but the project would almost certainly founder on the rock of prepositions. I am not sure why their use diverged so differently, but diverge they certainly did.

Comment: @Robusto Wasn't it an American who coined the expression 'If it's Tuesday, this must be Belgium'? Clearly one of the many who could laugh at themselves. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_It's_Tuesday,_This_Must_Be_Belgium

Comment: Perhaps you don't see a distinction between laughing at oneself and making fun of someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Translate into, not to
- At or during Christmas, both okay
- To ring someone or to ring someone up
- It starts at about eight, or around eight o'clock
- To travel around or through a place
- "Look about yourself" means "consider yourself"; "look around" is in the physical sense
- A speech on or about something. *On* may sound a bit more formal.